# Command __ not found

Tags: discord, webhooks, discord.py

I have a webhook cog for a discord bot I'm making. I want to make the embarrass command (in the webhook cog) trigger a webhook to be created with a user's name and pfp, which is working just fine. however, I also want this command to be able to be set onto a specific user, and that is where the problem arises. When I try to add a member parameter into the embarrass function, so it looks like: async def embarrass(self, ctx, member: discord.Member
it doesn't work. every time I execute the command after that I get a "command embarrass not found" error. this holds true regardless of if I pass through the paramter, and if I add member: discord.Member = None to it to make it not required; nothing I've done works. I would greatly appreciate any help on this topic.

Here is my main.py:

```
import random
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import json
import keep_alive
from discord import Game
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import datetime
import re
import time
from subprocess import call
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
import text
import os
TOKEN = os.environ['token']
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")

startup_extensions = ["Cog.Cog_Template", "Cog.webhooks"]


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    # On read, after startup
    print(f"Connecting...\nConnected {bot.user}\n")  # Send message on connected


if __name__ == "__main__":  # When script is loaded, this will run
    for extension in startup_extensions:
        try:
            bot.load_extension(extension)  # Loads cogs successfully
        except Exception as e:
            exc = '{}: {}'.format(type(e).__name__, e)
            print('Failed to load extension {}\n{}'.format(extension, exc))


keep_alive.keep_alive()
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

And here is my cog file (its called webhook.py and its in a folder called Cog:

```
from discord import Webhook, RequestsWebhookAdapter
from discord.ext import commands
import random

embarrasslist = ["I use and throughly like airpods","I respond with \"^\" to everything because I'm too dumb to have an original thought of my own","The only time I ever go outside is for school","I made a discord server where exactly 3 people joined, and they were were my alt accounts.","I get legitimately scared when I play five nights at freddy's","I play PC Games with a steam controller","I unironically use 69 in my usernames","I cried myself to sleep when I found out that my favourite chair had a dent in it","My parent's gave me a PS Move instead of a Wii for christmas","I unironically watch Ali-A","I spam .embarrass because I am very narcissistic and want to see my face on a bot", "I couldn't teach my son how to ride a bike cause I can't ride one myself","I own a sonic pillow and I kiss it every night before I go to sleep","I set my favorite 3ds game to system settings because I thought I was being clever","I set my favorite 3ds game to system settings because I can't buy any more games","Paul Blart: Maul Cop is my favorite movie","I thought shrek 3 wasn't bad","I have a gameinformer subscription","It took me a full day to beat the first level of super mario bros","My favorite emote is :joy:","I spent 2 hours learning how to make a new folder on my computer","I torrented fortnite"]
class WebHooks(commands.Cog, name="WebHooks"):
    global embarrasslist
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    @commands.command(name="embarrass")
    async def embarrass(self, ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
        """Send a message as a webhook"""
        if member != None:
          user = member
        elif member = None:
          user = ctx.message.author
        embarrassnumber = random.randint(0,21)
        embarrassment = embarrasslist[embarrassnumber]
        looking_webhooks = await ctx.channel.webhooks()
        if looking_webhooks:
            for webhook in looking_webhooks:
                if webhook.name == "NexInfinite-GitHub":
                    await send_webhook(webhook, embarrassment, ctx, user)
                    return
                else:
                    pass
        webhook = await ctx.channel.create_webhook(name="NexInfinite-GitHub")

        await send_webhook(webhook, embarrassment, ctx, user)
        return
    @commands.command(name="embaras", aliases = ["embarras","embarass"])
    async def embarras(self, ctx):
        """Send a message as a webhook"""
        cantspell = "I don't know how to spell *embarrass* properly"
        looking_webhooks = await ctx.channel.webhooks()
        if looking_webhooks:
            for webhook in looking_webhooks:
                if webhook.name == "NexInfinite-GitHub":
                    await send_webhook(webhook, cantspell, ctx)
                    return
                else:
                    pass
        webhook = await ctx.channel.create_webhook(name="NexInfinite-GitHub")
        await send_webhook(webhook, cantspell, ctx)
        return


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(WebHooks(bot))


async def send_webhook(webhook, message, ctx, uservar):
    webhook_id = webhook.id
    webhook_token = webhook.token
    webhook = Webhook.partial(int(webhook_id),
                              f"{webhook_token}",
                              adapter=RequestsWebhookAdapter())
    webhook.send(f'{message}', username=f"{ctx.uservar.display_name}",
                 avatar_url=ctx.uservar.avatar_url)  # Sends the message as the author
```

I am running this on repl.it so thats why I import keep_alive, and I have another cog that I added with other commands but that doesn’t seem to be the issue either. I can add it if you request it however.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to import discord at the top, so I couldn't successfully use discord.Member. Importing discord solved this issue.